# how to check simple paths exist in bipartite graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have an outgoing neighborhood structure of a directed graph:

```
a{f}=[d e];
a{d}=[c];
a{e}=[c h];
a{h}=[b];
a{c}=[a b];
```

where `a{f}=[d e]` means that nodes `d` and `e` are the outgoing neighborhood of node `f`.

Now, my goal is to determine whether there exist two paths, one is from `f` to `a`, the other is from `f` to `b`, whose nodes are not allowed to be intersected each other?

For this example, the answer is affirmative, because we can find the two paths:

```
p1: f->d->c->a
p2: f->e->h->b
```

But when we delete the edge `h->b` in the graph, the answer is NO, because even if there are two paths:

```
p1: f->d->c->a
p3: f->e->c->b
```

however, the path `p3` has a node `c` intersected with path `p1`.

```
  f
 / \
d   e
 \ / \
  c   h
 / \ /
a   b
```

My question is: is there any algorithms to check the existence of the two paths?

Comment: The Hopcroft-Karp algorithm checks for node-disjoint shortest augmenting paths to compute a maximum matching in bipartite graphs; using a similar technique to the one used in that algorithm, you might get what you want in time O(|V|^0.5 * |E|) which is the time complexity of Hopcroft-Karp. That's what I'd have a look at, apart from the suggestions in the answers that were already posted. Note one thing though, Hopcroft-Karp out of the box only finds node-disjoint paths of equal length. You'd also have to adapt it so the "source" f doesn't mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are the **dominators** of `A` and `B` in a flowgraph with starting point `F`. `V` dominates `A` if every path from `F` to `A` passes through `V`. So, for your particular problem, you can:

- Compute and go through all the dominators of `A`, mark those vertices except `F`
- Compute and go through all the dominators of `B`, and if any of those vertices are marked:

  -> `A` and `B` have at least one common dominator `D`, so no two vertex-disjoint (apart from both containing `F`) paths `F->A` and `F->B` can exist, because every path `F->A` and every path `F->B` passes through `D`.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)#Algorithms

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with a max-flow algorithm by:

1. Construct a directed graph by splitting each of your vertices into an entry vertex and exit vertex
2. Add an edge from entry(i) to exit(i) with capacity 1 for each pair based on vertex i
3. Add an edge from exit(i) to entry(j) with capacity 1 for each edge i->j in your original graph
4. Add an extra terminal vertex e
5. Add an edge from the exit vertex for every destination (in your case exit(a) and exit(b)) to vertex e with capacity 1
6. Compute the [maximum flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) from exit(f) to e

If and only if the max flow is 2, then there are two vertex-disjoint paths from f to a/b.

### Example Python code

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()
a={'f':'de','d':'c','e':'ch','h':'b','c':'ab','a':'','b':''}
for v in a:
    i='entry_'+v
    j='exit_'+v
    G.add_edge(i,j,capacity=1)
    for dest in a[v]:
        G.add_edge(j,'entry_'+dest,capacity=1)
for dest in 'ab':
    G.add_edge('exit_'+dest,'e',capacity=1)
print nx.max_flow(G,'exit_f','e')

G.remove_edge('exit_h','entry_b')
print nx.max_flow(G,'exit_f','e')
```

This prints

```
2 (meaning that in the original graph there are 2 vertex disjoint paths)
1 (meaning that once we remove h->b, there is only 1 vertex disjoint path)
```